Corrupted font when exporting to .pdf
I am using InDesign 18.2.1 to download and edit an Adobe template. When exporting (crtl+e) to .pdf, some of the letters disappeared using the original font. Using InDesign friendly fonts (e.g. Calibri, Arial), it's gone to worse as the text completely corrupts except for a few lines after exporting: letters overlay or are changed to all-caps nonsense 'ASJKHFADJHFLJLJDAF'. Once I even got Kanji (somehow). None of this happens in the overview print.
I've tried saving the file as IDML and back to .indd. I've tried different fonts: if I change the first 2 pages everything exports fine, but if I change the whole file to a different font it all corrupts again. I have ticked the box that allows embedding for fonts and 'autoactivate adobe fonts' - it doesn't change anything. What can I try?

Depending on the Indesign document structure, did you replace the font using the Character and Paragraph styles palette? Try to double check the Preflight window in Indesign or Acrobat whether the corrupted font family is still listed. Check your system font folder for duplicate fonts which might interfere.

I did use styles listed in the Character and Paragraph overview. The Preflight window marks a few text frames as overset text (this was known to me; these are a few images that stretch/overlap) but nothing regarding the corrupt font family. In the end I "fixed" it by using 3-4 different fonts throughout the file - this resulted in no corrupted fonts in the exported .pdf (but took 20 versions to get right).

Double check the Preflight window in Indesign or Acrobat whether the corrupted font family is still listed and replace the font using the Character and Paragraph styles palette. Check your system font folder for duplicate fonts which might interfere.
